# Singleton - How they work with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, singleton

When I create a singleton in my ASP.NET application, what exactly is it's "scope"?
Is the same singleton instance in memory likely to be used by more that one request from different IPs?

i.e. John puts information into a singleton via a form, and then Susie comes in and puts information into the singleton. Is it possible that John and Susie are storing information into the same instance?

Comment: We'll need more implementation information to help us determine the right answer here.  It depends what scope the reference to the singleton is created in - e.g. a static member - yes almost certainly same instance.  HttpContext.Items, almost certainly no etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Static Variables in ASP.net are shared across the entire application, for all users. Also be careful with static constructors, as they also run exactly once.

Microsoft has a KB Article, [Troubleshooting ASP.NET applications with the use of static keywords (893666)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893666)

If you need "Per User Static Variables", Session or HttpContext.Items might be what you need.

Comment: Joshua said singleton - but didn't indicate static or otherwise - without this information the scope unknown - for example his "singleton" could well have been static method backed by HttpContext.Items

Comment: @stephbu Out of interest, how would you implement Singleton in .net without statics? Serializing an instance object to an external store? Or am I missing something?

Comment: The perception of "singleton" is only from the viewpoint of the scope/container - so for example even with statics - they are only singletons in context of the appdomain.  I'm not doubting that statics are a great way to create singletons in scope of appdomain, I'm emphasizing we don't know the scope.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are making a stereotypical Singleton (implementation you would see in a state-oriented environment) then that means that your singleton will be shared across the entire application and with ALL users.

static items are stored in server memory but are not on a per user basis. You would need to utilize something like the Session for that scenario.